# How to create a self extracting installer (exe) with FinalBuilder

Tags: installation, self-extracting, finalbuilder, iexpress

To manually create a self-extracting executable, I use [IExpress](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd346760.aspx) which is built in to Windows (edit: its from the IE Adminstration Kit).  I'm looking for a way to automate this using FinalBuilder, our builder of choice.  Is there a way to do this?  Maybe a batch script that can be run from FinalBuilder?

Comment: Just to clarify: IExpress is *not* "built in to Windows". It's part of the [IE Adminstration Kit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd361863.aspx). It's also a wizard, which means it goes through step by step asking for user input. There are many other installation builders that lend themselves to scripting. Do you need an MSI or a stand-alone executable Setup.exe? (Actually, search here for `[windows] installers` for many posts, including a few lists.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, i was unaware (obviously). i need a stand-alone setup.exe

Comment: [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org). It's free, allows you to script the entire installation, has a scripting language that allows you to extend the built in scripting, and can be fully automated from your build process. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/3767/62576.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with 7zip's sfx feature, which you can get when you download the 7zip extras.

http://7zsfx.info/en/